# PHP find the charset set by setlocale

Tags: php, utf-8

All my websites use UTF-8 as charset. But there are some issues when setting `setlocale` and getting localized strings from `strftime` for month names and weekday names.

1. issue: Localizing month names do not work on the server.
2. issue: How to know if the locale stings are in UTF-8 or ISO?

Concrete: I set the locale like this:

```
$locales = ['de_DE.utf-8/utf-8', 'de_DE@euro/utf-8', 'de_DE', 'de-DE', 'german', 'de', 'ge'];
$locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, $locales);
```

On my development system (Windows 10, XAMPP) it finds and sets $locale = 'de-DE'.
On my server (Linux, Apache) it finds and sets $locale = 'de_DE'.

Because the PHP built in DateTime class doesn't support localized names, I created a class which extends the DateTime class:

```
class DateTimeExt extends DateTime {

    private function isUTF8() : bool {
        $locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, null);
        if (!$locale) return false;
        $locale = strtoupper($locale);
        return strpos($locale, 'UTF8') !== false || strpos($locale, 'UTF-8') !== false;
    }

    public function weekdayName() : string {
        $weekday = strftime('%A', $this->getTimestamp());
        if (!$weekday) return 'unknown';
        return $this->isUTF8() ? $weekday : utf8_encode($weekday);
    }

    public function monthName() : string {
        $month = strftime('%B', $this->getTimestamp());
        if (!$month) return 'unknown';
        return $this->isUTF8() ? $month : utf8_encode($month);
    }
}
```

The test with:

```
$date = new DateTimeExt('2021-03-02');
echo $date->weekdayName().'<br />';
echo $date->monthName().'<br />';
```

results on the dev environment:

```
// Dienstag
// März
```

Both are correct. Without the UTF-8 encoding it would give back:

```
// Dienstag
// M�rz
```

But on the server it results to:

```
// Dienstag
// March
```

WTF??? The server can localize the weekday, but not the month, and defaults to english? Why that? This is issue No.1.

Issue No.2 is the detection whether the set locale supports UTF-8. My function `isUTF8` just gets the current locale and searches for the patterns `'UTF8'` and `'UTF-8'` in it, and if yes I assume UTF-8, otherwise i assume ISO and a needed UTF-8 encoding. I don't think this is the smartest thinkable way to do this and maybe quite error-prone. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locales are system-dependent. Make sure that the locales you want show up in `locale -a`.

Mucking about with `setLocale()` is global and can have unintended side-effects, I would suggest [`IntlDateFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) instead:

```php
$d = new DateTime('2021-03-15');
$mon_formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('de_DE', IntlDateFormatter::NONE, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
$mon_formatter->setPattern('MMMM');

$day_formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('de_DE', IntlDateFormatter::NONE, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
$day_formatter->setPattern('EEEE');

var_dump(
    $mon_formatter->format($d),
    $day_formatter->format($d)
);
```

Output

```
string(5) "März"
string(6) "Montag"
```

Or, more likely, format the entire date using a [pattern you define](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Your code works very well on my home XAMPP, but sadly not at all on the server. I get for both the default english names, Tuesday and March. I looked with `locale -a` for the installed locales and found `de_DE`, `de_DE.utf8` and `de_DE@euro`. With each of them I get the same result, the default english names. I could try the `de_AT` or `de_CH` variants, but I am not very hopeful.

Comment: Found the bug! I had to do `$locale = setlocale(LC_TIME, null);` instead of `$locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, null);` to get the correct used locale string. Now it works on the server, too.